# Pandas Merge duplicating all rows

Tags: python, pandas, merge

I am trying to merge two dataframes to find any new entries.  Currently the two dataframes are identical.

Dataframe A

```
    BusinessName                        Ubi             IdentifierValue
0   CHULA VISTA PAINTING/SERVICES       604000010       CHULAVP841MQ
1   MANU TECH LLC                       604000040       MANUTTL833BL
2   HAWTHORN LANDSCAPE MTRILS INC       604000042       HAWTHLM845MM
3   M M R CONSTRUCTION LLC              604000082       MMRCOCL848MM
4   HURTADO PAINTING                    604000120       HURTAP*831JJ
```

Dataframe B

```
        BusinessName                    Ubi             IdentifierValue
0   CHULA VISTA PAINTING/SERVICES       604000010       CHULAVP841MQ
1   MANU TECH LLC                       604000040       MANUTTL833BL
2   HAWTHORN LANDSCAPE MTRILS INC       604000042       HAWTHLM845MM
3   M M R CONSTRUCTION LLC              604000082       MMRCOCL848MM
4   HURTADO PAINTING                    604000120       HURTAP*831JJ
```

When I merge on the Ubi it duplicates all of the rows.

```
A = A[['Ubi']]
B = B[['Ubi']]
A = A.merge(B, how='outer', indicator=True)
A


    Ubi         _merge
0   604000010.0 left_only
1   604000040.0 left_only
2   604000042.0 left_only
3   604000082.0 left_only
4   604000120.0 left_only
5   604000010.0 right_only
6   604000040.0 right_only
7   604000042.0 right_only
8   604000082.0 right_only
9   604000120.0 right_only
```

If I merge with just the business name though it works as expected.

```
A = A[['BusinessName']]
B = B[['BusinessName']]
A = A.merge(B, how='outer', indicator=True)
A

BusinessName                        _merge
0   CHULA VISTA PAINTING/SERVICES   both
1   MANU TECH LLC                   both
2   HAWTHORN LANDSCAPE MTRILS INC   both
3   M M R CONSTRUCTION LLC          both
4   HURTADO PAINTING                both
```

It would be best to merge on the Ubi, but I can't seem to find the problem.  The Ubi column is an Int64 whereas the other columns are Objects.  I did notice when I merge on the Ubi column the column type switches to float64.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is problem different types, need same.

Check it:

```
print (A['Ubi'].dtype)
print (B['Ubi'].dtype)
```

So need:

```
A['Ubi'] = A['Ubi'].astype(str)
B['Ubi'] = B['Ubi'].astype(str)
```

Or:

```
A['Ubi'] = A['Ubi'].astype(int)
B['Ubi'] = B['Ubi'].astype(int)
```

Comment: Yes, check the dtypes first